# How to run python3 on google's dataproc pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, configuration, pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to run a pyspark job through Google Cloud Platform dataproc, but I can't figure out how to setup pyspark to run python3 instead of 2.7 by default.

The best I've been able to find is adding these [initialization commands](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/issues/25)

However, when I ssh into the cluster then
(a) `python` command is still python2,
(b) my job fails due to a python 2 incompatibility.

I've tried uninstalling python2 and also aliasing `alias python='python3'` in my init.sh script, but alas, no success.  The alias doesn't seem to stick.

I create the cluster like this

```
cluster_config = {
    "projectId": self.project_id,
    "clusterName": cluster_name,
    "config": {
        "gceClusterConfig": gce_cluster_config,
        "masterConfig": master_config,
        "workerConfig": worker_config,
        "initializationActions": [
            [{
            "executableFile": executable_file_uri,
            "executionTimeout": execution_timeout,
        }]
        ],
    }
}

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
api = build('dataproc', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

response = api.projects().regions().clusters().create(
    projectId=self.project_id,
    region=self.region, body=cluster_config
).execute()
```

My `executable_file_uri` is sits on google storage; `init.sh`:

```
apt-get -y update
apt-get install -y python-dev
wget -O /root/get-pip.py https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python /root/get-pip.py
apt-get install -y python-pip
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade six
pip install --upgrade gcloud
pip install --upgrade requests
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer to this [here](https://gist.github.com/cerisier/118c06d1a0147d1fb898218b57ba82a3/) such that my initialization script now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install tools
apt-get -y install python3 python-dev build-essential python3-pip
easy_install3 -U pip

# Install requirements
pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud==0.27.0
pip3 install --upgrade google-api-python-client==1.6.2
pip3 install --upgrade pytz==2013.7

# Setup python3 for Dataproc
echo "export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3" | tee -a  /etc/profile.d/spark_config.sh  /etc/*bashrc /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
echo "export PYTHONHASHSEED=0" | tee -a /etc/profile.d/spark_config.sh /etc/*bashrc /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
echo "spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED=0" >> /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

Comment: how to edit the [datalab.sh][https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/datalab/datalab.sh] script to include the python3 support ?

Comment: @Pablo, the link you reference is now broken.

Comment: For posterity, Dagang's answer (upgrade to Dataproc 1.4) is now the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Configure the Dataproc cluster's Python environment](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration) explained it in detail. Basically, you need init actions before 1.4, and the default is Python3 from Miniconda3 in 1.4+.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Conda init action to setup Python 3 and optionally install pip/conda packages: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/conda.

Something like:

`gcloud dataproc clusters create foo --initialization-actions \
gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/conda/bootstrap-conda.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/conda/install-conda-env.sh`

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to select python interpreter for pyspark.

1.If you want to set python3 as default, set `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3` while creating dataproc cluster. I added couple of code in the init scripts.

```
sudo echo "export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/effective-python.sh
source /etc/profile.d/effective-python.sh
```

2.Otherwise it's also possible to specify the python version through `--properties` to use while submitting pyspark job to dataproc cluster. The python version can be passed in the following way:

```
 --properties spark.pyspark.python=python3.7,spark.pyspark.driver=python3.7
```